# Resigned ipa won't install on iPhone 5

Tags: ios, iphone, ipa, codesign

I'm using the following terminal commands to re-sign an ipa: I unzip the ipa, copy in a new mobile provisioning profile, run codesign with a sign identity, and zip it back up into an ipa.

```
unzip -q My_App_Name.app
cp New_Mobile_Provision Payload/My_App_Name.app/embedded.mobileprovision
codesign -f -s 'my certificate' Payload/My_App_Name.app
zip -qr My_App_Name_Resigned.ipa Payload/
```

But when I use ios-deploy to try installing the result to an iPhone 5 (on iOS 9), it gets to 70% - verifying ipa- and fails. Anyone else seen this?

Answer (score 1):

Look at files in .app directory.
There may be more than one executable, library or framework.

You need to replace all the signature of them.